# How to check if a variable is a Set or Map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set

How can I check if a JavaScript variable is a `Set` or `Map`?

There is no equivalent to `Array.isArray()`, so my best guess is something like:

```
c.__proto__.constructor.name === 'Set'
```

Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of with that approach? Or a better way?

Comment: Does `instanceof` not work here? E.g., `if (thing instanceof Set) {...}`

Comment: Don't ever use `__proto__`, it's deprecated. Don't use `.constructor` to check for inheritance, use `instanceof` instead. If you really were looking for a specific constructor, don't use `.name`, but compare by reference. (None of these is specific to `Map`/`Set`, actually)

Answer (score 3):

If I've understand your question you can use `instanceof`.

Only check if your object is an instance of the desired object.

```js
var set = new Set();
var map = new Map();
console.log("set variable is Set object:",set instanceof Set)
console.log("map variable is Set object:",map instanceof Set)
console.log("set variable is Map object:",set instanceof Map)
console.log("map variable is Map object:",map instanceof Map)
```

In this example, using the syntaxis `myVariable instanceof MyObject` the output is true when the variable is the desired object, otherwise false.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.prototype.toString.call`, which is a robust solution that works for different frames as well.

```js
function isSet(obj){
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Set]';
}
function isMap(obj){
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Map]';
}
console.log(isSet(new Set));
console.log(isMap(new Map));
```

Comment: …robust, until someone tries to fool you with `{[Symbol.toStringTag]: 'Map'}`. `instanceof` is a better solution in general